Ubuntu app interaction with Windows OS
I'm start using Ubuntu application from Microsoft Store and main biggest problem is the copy/past text from Windows interface to the Linux command line and from Linux command line to Windows.
Becasue the standard options of marking as a copy and paste as right click of mouse or Shift+Insert doesn't work.
are here someone, who work with that ?
enter image description here
https://ubuntu.com/desktop/wsl

Have you tried middle-clicking when the text you want to paste is highlighted? I’m not sure if that works in WSL but works in full Ubuntu.

Or try Ctrl - Shift - V

Checked both option, but they doesn't work.
Thanks for Your quick response.

hi Will,
You was right. just there was necessary to change some parameteres.

Right-click on the title bar of the Ubuntu terminal window.
Select "Properties".
Turn on "Insert Mode" and "Use Ctrl+Shift+C/V as Copy/Paste"

And that's it !

Glad you solved it, well done. Do post your solution as an answer to your question then - might help someone else!
